# how do i connect a photodiode detecting laser?

Tags: sensor, infrared, photodiode

I want to send data through a tissue using a 850nm Laser diode.

I would like to know how to connect a PIN photodiode on the receiver side?

Comment: What data rate? Is it a proper laser or a VCSEL?

Comment: its a VCSEL that has a data up to 2.5 Gbps .

Comment: What data rate are you actually using? I've used a 1mW o/p VCSEL in the past at a data rate of about 500Mbps but had problems getting reliable data with them. I went for a 5mW divergent beam laser in the end and had no problems at distances up to about 20mm.

Comment: I ordred for the VCSEL and i m going to test it in the next week , its a 850 nm with data rate up to 2.5 Gbps and a output power of 1.5 mW. Are you sending your data in free space or through a sample? i saw many papers have got interresting result using this kind of vcsel .

Comment: Free space with an OPTEK photodiode and a MAX3746. I ended up using the MAX3746 and went for 1300nm laser and photodiode

Comment: do you have a schematic for the circuit ?

Comment: I can probably lay my hands on one. I'll post it as a possible answer tomorrow but the max3746 is fairly standard and to the data sheet but make sure its 5V supply is spot on +/- 0.1V despite what the pdf says. I was using the MAX to couple to the photodiode (c/w transimp amp).

Comment: @Andyaka i want to send data at data rate up to 50 Mbps, so if you have any idea, because i used the circuit below and it didn`t work for high frequency . thank you.

Comment: What op-amp did you use and what circuit values for C1 and R1? Most importantly what device did you use for D1?

Comment: i am using AD8015 , and am not using the same circuit as below, am using the circuit i found in the data sheet of the amplifier, for D1 it s a PHOTODIODE 850nm 5 mm clear TO-92.

Comment: The circuit is needed and as already asked the photodiode info i.e. a link

Comment: and what about the circuit on the data-sheet ? here is a link for the photodiode used : (http://www.digikey.ca/product-search/en?lang=en&site=ca&KeyWords=SFH206K)

Comment: the photodiode you linked has a switch time of 20ns. This means rise time + fall time plus another 20ns for stabilizing top and bottom of the waveform gives you 60ns and that equates to a frequency of 17MHz or 34Mbpsec. You are pushing you luck at 50Mbps. What about the laser you are using? What switching speed does this have and what circuit are you driving it with?

Comment: ok got that part, i have to change the phtodiode first, i am using opv380 http://www.digikey.ca/product-search/en?lang=en&site=ca&KeyWords=opv380 and am driving it with this circuit 
 ![C:\Users\moaly\Desktop\20130910_095317.jpg] i dont know how to upload it .

Comment: If you can post to a "share" site of some type I can read it from there. Regarding the VCSEL, I don't think it is fast enough either. If you look at this http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.optekinc.com%2Fdatasheets%2Fopv314.pdf&ei=bjcvUvAsotDsBpehgdAB&usg=AFQjCNF7bkpYFoVt8_QTsmyhyYEYIz0RVw&bvm=bv.51773540,d.ZGU, it is recommended for 2.5Gbps data transmission whereas the device you linked doesn't recommend it suitable for any data rate.

Answer (score 5):

The usual configuration is to use a transimpedance amplifier. This takes the current output of the photodiode and converts it to a low-impedance voltage signal.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foZZhy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The gain of the amplifier is set by R1. The maximum gain achievable without ringing in the response will depend on the op-amp used. C1 is used to reduce high-frequency noise. OA1 is chosen based on noise and bandwidth. The parasitic capacitance at the inverting input of the op-amp has a strong effect on overall performance.

With an appropriately chosen op-amp this circuit can be used up to at least 40 or 50 MHz (probably someone will comment that it is usable at higher frequencies --- 40-50 MHz is just the highest where I've seen it used). For higher frequencies you may need a specially designed receiver, which is basically the same circuit but integrated to reduce parasitics.

Comment: thank you for your answer .
do you think the AD8015 is a good choice for the amplifier ?

Comment: Op-amp choice depends on the bandwidth you need, the laser and pin diode you're using, the minimum power you need to be able to detect, and the minimum SNR you need. Also more mundane details like what power supplies you have available, size of footprint you need to fit the circuit in to, etc.

Comment: AD8015 would be a replacement for this whole circuit. You have to judge if it meets the needs of your system. If you need more than 50 MHz bandwidth I would consider it as an alternative to the op-amp circuit.